# Place parentheses around characters separated by comma using regex in r

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'd like to add parentheses around grouped text separated by a comma using `stringr`. So if there is text that is separated by one or more commas, then I'd like parentheses around the text. There will always be a "=" before this type of string begins and there will either be a space or nothing (vector ends) after the string. Is there a generalized way to do this? Here's a sample problem:

Sample:

```
a <- data.frame(Rule = c("A=0 & B=Grp1,Grp2", "A=0 & B=Grp1,Grp3,Grp4 & C=1"))
a
                          Rule
1            A=0 & B=Grp1,Grp2
2 A=0 & B=Grp1,Grp3,Grp4 & C=1
```

Desired Output:

```
                            Rule
1            A=0 & B=(Grp1,Grp2)
2 A=0 & B=(Grp1,Grp3,Grp4) & C=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another potential solution. I have altered the example input to show that it works with multiple "Grp's" per line:

```r
library(stringr) 
a <- data.frame(Rule = c("A=0 & B=Grp1,Grp2",
                         "A=0 & B=Grp1,Grp3,Grp4 & C=1 & D=Grp5,Grp6"))

str_replace_all(a$Rule, "=([^, &]+,[^ $]+)", "=(\\1)")
#> [1] "A=0 & B=(Grp1,Grp2)"                           
#> [2] "A=0 & B=(Grp1,Grp3,Grp4) & C=1 & D=(Grp5,Grp6)"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Explanation:

regex = `"=([^, &]+,[^ $]+)", "=(\\1)"`

`=(` starting with an equals sign, capture a group

`[^, &]+,` with one or more characters that aren't ",", " ", and "&" followed by a comma

`[^ $]+)` followed by one or more characters that aren't " " or the end of the line ("$")

`=(\\1)` then replace the equals sign and add parentheses around the captured group (e.g. the Grp1,Grp2)

Comment: Quick warning - the regex here will also match `=Grp1,g\`56';][` or any such random noise after the first group, as long as it doesn't contain a space.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

Find: `(([A-Za-z\d]+,)+[A-Za-z\d]+)`

Replace: `($1)`

Explanation:

`[A-Za-z\d]` is any alphanumeric character.

The inner group looks for 1 or more copies of groups of alphanum characters separated by commas. (e.g. `Abcd1,Abcd2,`)

The outer group then looks for the closing alphanumeric group, which doesn't have a comma after it. (e.g. `Abcd3`)

These are concatenated then the whole group is captured.

Last thing to do is the replacement, which is pretty self explanatory.